# Merging Two Strings while building view in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, string-concatenation, create-view

I am trying to build sqlite view `vwCOMPLETE_INFO` from 2 tables (`CUSTOMERS` and `CITIES`)

but i have problem in merging the `FIRST_NAME` and `LAST_NAME` to build `FULL_NAME` Column in the new view

```
CREATE VIEW vwCOMPLETE_INFO AS SELECT (CUSTOMERS.FIRST_NAME || CUSTOMERS.LAST_NAME AS FULL_NAME), CUSTOMERS.AGE, CITIES.NAME FROM CITIES JOIN CUSTOMERS ON CUSTOMER.CITY_ID = CITY.ID;
```

what could fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are including **`AS FULL_NAME`** as part of the term that builds the column's data, rather than where it should be as after the term so that it names the column accordingly.

In short **`AS FULL_NAME`** should be the other-side of/outside/after the parenthesis's. i.e. **`....CUSTOMERS.LAST_NAME) AS FULL_NAME.....`** rather than `.....CUSTOMERS.LAST_NAME AS FULL_NAME).....`

Try

```
CREATE VIEW vwCOMPLETE_INFO AS SELECT (CUSTOMERS.FIRST_NAME || CUSTOMERS.LAST_NAME) AS FULL_NAME, CUSTOMERS.AGE, CITIES.NAME FROM CITIES JOIN CUSTOMERS ON CUSTOMER.CITY_ID = CITY.ID;
```